# Do swarm clean up containers/images or i should run system prune?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

if all container management on node is done by swarm, are there any "leek" in stopped containers and old images? So should i regularly run `docker system prune` or all done by swarm ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a cron job that runs dockerCleanUp.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
docker rm $(docker ps -aq)
docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -q)
docker rmi $(docker images -aq)
```

prune may not cleanup all containers/volumes/images but this will work pretty much every time

Also, you might check out the repo below. pretty awesome service you can run in a swarm to cleanup. Basically... It runs a container to cleanup the swarm...

https://github.com/spotify/docker-gc

Comment: docker rm $(docker volume ls -q)
will not work because  docker rm taked containers not voluem names
better is docker volume prune

Comment: Good catch updated the answer, should have been `docker volume rm`  prune will not always work, this will work every time